# Why does the Express built-in middleware use parenthesis syntax while custom-made doesn't?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

why does express inbuilt middleware use a paranthesis syntax like app.use(express.json()) while custom made doesnt use paranthesis like app.use(logger)

Its just throws error with paranthesis

i am not sure if it is in docs

Comment: `express.json()` returns a function that works like your `logger`, it just takes (optional) parameters to configure what exactly the middleware function should do.

Answer (score 0):

`use` takes a function that handles the request and potentially writes to the response. Calling `json()` **returns** such a function while your `logger` already **is** such a function.